# .htaccess redirect which don't have query string and first level from root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect url which don't have /? query string to query string like this

http://domain.com/randcode to http://domain.com/?id=randcode

just needed one slash level redirect like : http://domain.com/randcode or http://domain.com/randcode/

don't want to redirect like : http://domain.com/dir/othercode

Please help in this i am not so good writing the htaccess

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.html)[^/]+)/?$ /?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you Anubhava :) , just last request i am getting the index.html at the end of redirect like : id=index.html when i visit to root domain , can i exclude index.html 

domain.com  and it redirect me domain.com?id=index.html don't want to redirect on the root of domain. 
Thanks again for the Great Help :)